# "mini-skydiver" vs "miniskydiver."

Tags: style, hyphens

Example sentence:

> The cockroach fell to the floor like a mini-skydiver and scurried out of the bathroom.

Some style guides say that you shouldn't use a hyphen with the prefix "mini."

But I think you should use a hyphen when the combination is unusual?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't agree that you should *never* use a hyphen. Compound nouns can be one word, two words without a hyphen, or two hyphenated words. Some compound nouns may have come about through natural usage, but others are constructed as brand names, and so the creators decide on the style choice.

Examples:

- Mini-break (a short holiday/vacation, sometimes written [with a hyphen](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/mini-break), sometimes [without](https://loghouseholidays.co.uk/17-best-mini-break-ideas-uk/))
- Minibike (a [small motorcycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minibike))
- Mini Metro (British [car](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Austin_Metro) from the 1980s)

As you say, if the combination is 'unusual' (ie it is not commonly used) then a hyphen is a good way of clearly indicating that you have created a compound noun and that these words should be treated as a noun together.

Comment: The BMC style for the 1959 Morris model name was 'Mini-Minor' with a hyphen (they already made a bigger Morris Minor). As the cars gained popularity, the public called them 'Minis' and this became the official model name in the 1960s. In 1980 a 'supermini' small car design was at first called the 'Austin miniMetro' [sic] and then the 'Austin Metro'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Interesting. I didn't know this but it sort of backs up my point that there's no standardisation and I'm surprised that any credible style guide would be so dogmatic about this.

Comment: I feel the same way. In the mid-1960s, the UK press was full of stories and pictures of young women wearing 'mini-skirts', 'mini skirts' and 'miniskirts'. I think that maybe there is an initial hyphenation stage followed by amalgamation.